# Put in string int and text

Tags: objective-c, stringwithformat

I want to put in string int and text.

I have this code: `chipsS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", chips];`

What to do?

Comment: Exactly what  output you reqiure? Because the line you have written is correct, so what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: Do you want to put sorry what? Who? Where? HMM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stringVariable = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i - %@", intVariable, stringVariable];`